# getent passwd returns nothing on openldap server on centos 7 (minimum)

Tags: centos, openldap

I setup ldap server on centos 7 minimum and got both getent passwd user and ldapsearch working. Then I proceed to setting up a client and that worked fine too, including getent passwd and ldapsearch commands. Then I setup a second client after some issues which were caused I believe more by copy and paste got the client-2 also working on getent and ldapsearch commands. Of course all on a VM machine.

But the amazing thins is on ldap server, getent passwd will NOT return any ldap user info, ldapsearch on it works. getent passwd works on both clients but not the server. I do not believe I have changed anything on ldapserver at all, after all it answers the clients correctly. Any ideas where I should look? I looked at ldap.conf, having defind or not defined URI and BASE make no difference. Thank you for any light on this matter.

Answer (score 0):

I had to run the following to make ldap server run getent passwd ldap-user correctly

authconfig --enableldap --enableldapauth --ldapserver="instructor.example.com" --ldapbasedn="dc=davinci,dc=example,dc=com" --update

Of course you have to use your own domain name and server. Two files would be touched:

/etc/nsswitch.conf
/etc/pam.d/system-auth